# Error in as.data.frame.default(dtm) : cannot coerce class "c("DocumentTermMatrix", "simple_triplet_matrix")" to a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a similar problem, I downloaded a large tweet file from the net
     saved it as     data.txt and loaded into R using rstudio (import dataset).
    but had errors and cannot continue.

```
  This is step by step on what i did and the errors i had.

# required packages
library(twitteR)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(tm)
library(XML)
library(SnowballC) 


 data<- read.csv("~/data/datasStream.txt", header=FALSE , sep = "," )
```

I have 3425 observations and 97 variables

```
## i load it to corpus

corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(data)) ## 97 elements 17.4 MB

## i cleaned the data using 

corpus = tm_map (corpus, tolower)

corpus = tm_map (corpus, stripWhitespace)

corpus = tm_map (corpus, stemDocument)

corpus = tm_map (corpus, PlainTextDocument)

# remove unnecessary spaces
corpus = gsub("[ \t]{2,}", "", corpus)
corpus = gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", corpus)


# remove NAs in corpus
corpus = corpus[!is.na(corpus)]

dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
```

dtm

```
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 97, terms: 151132)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 201231/14458573
Sparsity           : 99%
Maximal term length: 1775
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)


adtm <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.75)

adtm
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 97, terms: 270)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 11962/14228
Sparsity           : 54%
Maximal term length: 33
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)


df1 =  as.data.frame (m=as.matrix (adtm)) 

Error in as.data.frame.default(dtm) : cannot coerce class "c("DocumentTermMatrix", "simple_triplet_matrix")" to a data.frame
```

How can i resolve this problem? I want to perform a k-means clustering and word cloud with the data.

This is a sample data:

{"created_at":"Wed Feb 27 14:24:12 +0000 2013","id":306771719996186625,"id_str":"306771719996186625","text":"@Joeypearce we've got another bellend coming to see the car I'm having too help clean :-/ I'll see you when work ends ! X","source":"\u003ca href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":306763650054627328,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"306763650054627328","in_reply_to_user_id":127665137,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"127665137","in_reply_to_screen_name":"Joeypearce","user":{"id":274997668,"id_str":"274997668","name":"Ell Beaton \u00a9","screen_name":"Ell_Beaton","location":"","url":null,"description":"Go Glen, Or Go Home.","protected":false,"followers_count":147,"friends_count":85,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Thu Mar 31 12:44:39 +0000 2011","favourites_count":132,"utc_offset":0,"time_zone":"London","geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":1087,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"1A1B1F","profile_background_image_url":"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/768018009/7a0b3fe303f234e8d6a5429bb9ede9a9.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/768018009/7a0b3fe303f234e8d6a5429bb9ede9a9.jpeg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3304123896/606a7413bce208a1a38b1eb41fd017c9_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3304123896/606a7413bce208a1a38b1eb41fd017c9_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https://si0.twimg.com/profile_banners/274997668/1361751912","profile_link_color":"F50E0E","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"252429","profile_text_color":"666666","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[52.43718380,-2.14324244]},"coordinates":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-2.14324244,52.43718380]},"place":{"id":"ddeec3dc241e5b6a","url":"http://api.twitter.com/1/geo/id/ddeec3dc241e5b6a.json","place_type":"city","name":"Dudley","full_name":"Dudley, Dudley","country_code":"GB","country":"United Kingdom","bounding_box":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-2.191947,52.426012],[-2.191947,52.558221],[-2.011849,52.558221],[-2.011849,52.426012]]]},"attributes":{}},"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"Joeypearce","name":"Joey Pearce","id":127665137,"id_str":"127665137","indices":[0,11]}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"medium"}

Comment: I can't replicate this.  Without a reproducible example (including data) providing assistance is difficult at best.

Comment: i have included a sample data.

Comment: Can you post the result of `dput(adtm)` instead?

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those pains of R text mining.  The `dtm` and subsequent `adtm` both have two class types.

```
class(dtm)
[1] "DocumentTermMatrix"    "simple_triplet_matrix"
```

The same is true for the transposition, term document matrix.  You can solve this by first turning the `dtm`,`adtm` (or if you made a `tdm`) into a matrix.I tested this on 1000 tweets and was able to do the coercion.

```
adtm.m<-as.matrix(adtm)
adtm.df<-as.data.frame(adtm.m)
```

or you can nest the functions:

```
adtm.df<-as.data.frame(as.matrix(adtm))
```

It is a bit clunky but get the job done you can check the new class here.

```
class(adtm.df)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because `R` 's coercion code, quite rightly IMHO,  refuses to try to convert arbitrary classes into data frames.  There are two reasons.  THe usual one is that the class in question can be "ragged,' i.e. any attempt to turn into a `data.frame` would yield rows or columns of unequal length.  The second reason is that there simply may be no defined coercion method for the object in question, which would be the fault of whoever wrote the package in question.  This is a much rarer condition so far as I know.

You probably will have to manually (e.g. via a loop or other construct) extract the records inside your object and figure out how to build up a matrix-like object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,the data is unstructured, i.e i downloaded some tweet files. from the codes above, it seem ok until when i wanted to do data frame. Is there an alternative of doing it?

Comment: It may not have a structure, but it sure has `class` attributes.  Looks like you may need to read up on the basics of `R`.  For the moment, please type `dput( adtm)` and copy a portion of the  results into your question; also the results of `str(adtm)`. That will allow us to see what's going on.

Comment: Hi Carl,  str(adtm)
List of 6
 $ i       : int [1:12616] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ j       : int [1:12616] 1 2 3 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 ...
 $ v       : num [1:12616] 3171 1 21 11 1 ...
 $ nrow    : int 97
 $ ncol    : int 287
 $ dimnames:List of 2
  ..$ Docs : chr [1:97] "character(0)" "character(0)" "character(0)" "character(0)" ...
  ..$ Terms: chr [1:287] "0000" "012118" "012119" "012120" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "DocumentTermMatrix" "simple_triplet_matrix"
 - attr(*, "weighting")= chr [1:2] "term frequency" "tf"
>can't figure out whats in dput(adtm) cos its mixture of # and words. tx

Comment: Roughly speaking `dput()` translates objects (like your `adtm`) into code that can be used by enyone reading this code to generate an identical object (see `?dput` for details).